# Opening a named mutex by fully a qualified path

Tags: c, windows, winapi, mutex

Is it possible to open or query a named mutex, using [OpenMutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), by its full path qualification? For example:

```
HANDLE hHandleMutex = OpenMutex(READ_CONTROL, FALSE, 
            "\\Sessions\\1\\BaseNamedObjects\\SmartScreen_AppRepSettings_Mutex");
```

However, the function returns NULL and fails with error 161 (`ERROR_BAD_PATHNAME`: The specified path is invalid). Yes, the documentation says well about `\\Global` and `\\Local` prefixes and doesn't state anything about these full object names. However, MSDN doesn't state *everything*!

I am aware that we can query the same using `NtQuerySystemInformation`, `NtQueryObject` undocumented APIs. But that involves opening process, duplicating the token etc. I can very well use these APIs, but wanted a simple solution.

Let's assume that process is running as a SYSTEM account, so error 5 (access denied) won't be a problem. If that's the problem, I can handle it.

Comment: you need or use `Session\\1\\SmartScreen_AppRepSettings_Mutex` without leading \\ or if want full path - `ZwOpenMutant`

Comment: the `OpenMutex` looked in `\Sessions\<N>\BaseNamedObjects` or `\BaseNamedObjects` only. in both directories exist symbolic links `\BaseNamedObjects\Session` and `\Sessions\1\BaseNamedObjects\Session` which point to `\Sessions\BNOLINKS` where placed another symbolic links to per-session `BaseNamedObjects` directories. becasause this `"Session\\"` prefix and worked. or another way use native api `ZwOpenMutant` - in this case you free use any path

Comment: In short: OpenMutex processes the path it is given in a way that makes a raw path (as seen by the kernel) invalid.  So no, you can't do that, you must use a path that is meaningful to OpenMutex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong path. It should be:

```
"Session\\1\\SmartScreen_AppRepSettings_Mutex"
```

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382954.aspx) says that the `Session\` prefix is "reserved for system" use. Caveat emptor.

Comment: I'm afraid, but that's not correct David. I have tried both `"\\Sessions\\1\\BaseNamedObjects\\SessionImmersiveColorMutex"` and `"Sessions\\1\\BaseNamedObjects\\SessionImmersiveColorMutex"` which Process Explorer shows for Explorer.EXE. Both fail with the same error: 161.

Comment: It is correct. Works fine here. I wonder if you read the answer carefully. Try pasting the path from my answer. It's different from what you state in your comment. We did this at your previous question too.

Comment: Yes, it does for "Session\1" but not for "Sessions\1" or anything else. In short, it doesn't work for the full path as shown by Process Explorer. Probably OS is doing some mapping for "Session\1".

Comment: Obviously if you insist on using the path in the question, then it will fail. Use the path in my answer. Or, if you are happy with failure, use the path in your question. Do you want to succeed or not? This is a rather odd exchange. RbMm explains the details in his comments. None of this is documented so is liable to change in the future.